# Ninject InSingletonScope for asp.net mvc 4

Tags: ninject

I am trying to use the InSingletonScope for one of my service interface. However it is still creating a new instance of the object per web request. basically it behaves like an InRequestScope in my asp.net mvc 4 application.

I thought InSingletonScope is for the life time of the IIS process?

I register the following implementation for the interface in one of my NinjectModule. if I resolve it right away, repo1 and repo2 are actually the same instance. However, in my controller every request result in a new instance.

-------------------- Module registration

```
public class RepositoryModule : NinjectModule
{
    #region Overrides of NinjectModule

    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IFakeRepository>().To<FakeRepository>().InSingletonScope();

        // following code onle execute the constructor once
        var repo1String = Kernel.Get<IFakeRepository>().GetString();
        var repo2String = Kernel.Get<IFakeRepository>().GetString();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

-------------------- Repository interface and implementation

```
public interface IFakeRepository
{
    string GetString();
}

public class FakeRepository : IFakeRepository
{
    public FakeRepository()
    {
        // every web request execute this constructor
        Debug.Write("FakeRepository constructor called");
    }

    #region Implementation of IFackRepository

    public string GetString()
    {
        return "dummy string";
    }

    #endregion
}
```

------------------ web api controller

```
public class TestRepoController : ApiController
{
    public IFakeRepository FakeRepository { get; set; }

    public TestRepoController(IFakeRepository fakeRepository)
    {
        FakeRepository = fakeRepository;
    }

    public string Get()
    {
        return FakeRepository.GetString();
    }
}
```

----------------- web api route registration

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "TestTakeRoutePost",
         routeTemplate: "Fake",
         defaults: new { controller = "TestRepo" }
        );
```

----------------- NinjectWebCommon

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PNI.MediaServer.Application.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
```

[assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(PNI.MediaServer.Application.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        //load all Binds defined in the classes that inherit NinhectModule
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        // Set Web API Resolver
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new PniNinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);

        return kernel;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not enough code.  Show us the code that is working, and show us the code that is not working.  I suspect that your controller has a different instance of some object.

Comment: the whole setup is as simple as it can get, see the edited code. The constructor gets called on every web request. thanks

Comment: by the way, it is running under IIS Express from vs 2012

Comment: How did you register controller into NInject?

Comment: added the NinkectWebCommon that gets called on App start and app shutdown if this is what you are asking for , thanks

Comment: Did you ever made it work?